# Read data of a redis container from the host machine

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, redis-cli

I set up with docker-compose a redis container and a node app which uses the redis DB.

All works but I didn't mount any volume so I can't access the data of the redis DB from the host.
I also tried to deplou a container with another node app which tries to connect the redis DB but I can't connect to the redis client `Error: Redis connection to redis:6379 failed`

I don't want to `docker-compose down` the container because the redis data will be lost

Yes, I'm new to the Docker paradox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the redis image listed [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/), or one like it, you should be able to read the data by executing `redis-cli` in the same active container:

```
docker exec -it vigilant_fermat redis-cli
```

In my example, `vigilant_fermat` is the name of the container that Docker randomly assigned for me. Substitute the correct container name for your instance.